# How to change the scala code so it doesn't define timeout

Tags: scala

I would like to remove the timeout definition from the code below so it doesn't time out within the defined period. How can i achieve that?

```
val futureString: Future[String] = myTestActor.ask(Message).mapTo[String]
val timeoutFuture: Future[String] = play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout(throw new         TimeoutException(), 5 seconds)

Async {
  Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(futureString, timeoutFuture)) map {
    case result: String => println("got message " + result)
  } recover {
    case _: TimeoutException => "Timed out?"
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, there is `Duration.Inf` if you want to wait until it finished.

Comment: Replace `Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(futureString, timeoutFuture))` with `futureString`, remove the `recover` call.

Comment: Note that you do also have an implicit timeout used for the ask call, asking an actor spins up a temporary actor to receive the reply that you do not want to leak, if the timeout is reached with no reply you will get an AskTimeoutException